# Which is correct? in my folder/on my folder

Tags: grammar

So I am writing an email to my peers. So I wrote: "I am having troubles creating files in my folder". Or it should be "on my folder"?

Comment: This question is too basic for this site. Please support the proposed site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Comment: A *folder* can be a physical object, i.e, 2-Dimensional (in which case one uses *on*), or a container, i.e, metaphorically 3-Dimensional, even if it's all electronic (in which case one uses *in*). Most prepositions have some particular locative sense which shows up in metaphoric expansions; **all** containers are **3-D** and use *in*: *in the box, in the folder, in trouble, in the soup.*

Comment: @JohnLawler- trouble is not a container, I guess:)

Answer (score 9):

The folder *contains* the files, so "in my folder" is correct.